# Change the default value of CL_DEVICE_IMAGE3D_MAX_WIDTH

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencl, pyopencl, intel-oneapi

I have a 3d image with dimensions of more than 2048. When I try to load the image into the OpenCL program using the clCreateImage3d() call, I get an error. Because the underlying device can also support up to 2048 dimensions.

- CL_DEVICE_IMAGE3D_MAX_WIDTH - 2048
- CL_DEVICE_IMAGE3D_MAX_HEIGHT - 2048
- CL_DEVICE_IMAGE3D_MAX_DEPTH - 2048

Can I change the above default values ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not the default values, those are limits of your hardware/software.

Perhaps it might be changed in the future with a new driver, but there is nothing you can do as a user except adapt your code to take those limitations into account (process your image tile by tile?).